# When not to use auto as described in Bjarne Stroustrup book: A Tour of C++

Tags: c++

I was reading *A Tour of C++* and got confused as to the reason to use auto.

> We use auto where we don’t have a specific reason to mention the type
> explicitly. ‘‘Specific reasons’’ include:

> • The definition is in a large scope where we want to make the type clearly visible to readers
> of our code.

> • We want to be explicit about a variable’s range or precision (e.g., double rather than float).

I get the part that if we are in a large scope, we want people to see the types but I don't get the part about being explicit about a variable's range? What's meant by range here? Is it the same as precision?

**EDIT**: this question was closed but what the question I have asked is directed at what the author means and the example provided. Nothing broad about it.  I don't see how that can stray into opinion-land as I am not asking why auto should ever be used but what is meant by range. The comments provided provide an answer.

Comment: One of (unsigned) byte, short, int, long long, float, double.

Comment: @heretoinfinity For example types int and long long int have different ranges of values.

Comment: Signed vs unsigned is another example.

Comment: @heretoinfinity Using auto can result in ambiguity.

Comment: Could either of you add an answer? I get the part of ambiguity and the need to go back and search for what the right-hand side returns.

Comment: "What's meant by range here? Is it the same as precision?"  No.  Range could be -128 to +127 for `signed char`, -32768 to +32767 for `signed short`.  `float` precision can be 3.14159f, but 3.141592653589 for `double`.  `auto` may not be good enough for the desired range or precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "range" of a variable in that sentence refers to the minimum and maximum values it can hold.  For example, the range of a `signed char` is typically -128 to 127.